# Making a FAT12 filesystem on a simple (operating system) file on linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, osdev, fat

I want to create a FAT12 filesystem on a simple file on linux (Example: ~/file), and  perhaps use xxd to view what exactly happens when a filesystem is created. This is just out of curiosity

I believe that we can use the mkfs command or something similar to achieve this.

Can this be done? and  how?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mkfs.

Comment: Moderation bike-shedding at its finest. Oh well, such is the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, create a 16 or 32MB file and format it with `mkfs.vfat`.

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=fat12.img bs=1M count=32
32+0 records in
32+0 records out
33554432 bytes (34 MB, 32 MiB) copied, 0.0212121 s, 1.6 GB/s

$ mkfs.vfat -F12 fat12.img
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)

$ file fat12.img
fat12.img: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x3c+2, OEM-ID "mkfs.fat", sectors/cluster 32, reserved sectors 32, root entries 512, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/FAT 32, sectors/track 32, heads 64, sectors 65536 (volumes > 32 MB), serial number 0xb1d9d2e8, unlabeled, FAT (12 bit)

$ mount -o loop fat12.img /mnt/
```

You can then perform I/O on the mount, observe the hexdump of the image file to observe the on-disk layout changes and correlate with the I/O.